# select all values of ASP.NET MVC2.0 ListBox when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to select all values of a ASP.NET MVC 2.0 ListBox when a checkBox is checked ?

Comment: with some JavaScript perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example here
http://www.qodo.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/selectall.html

and explanation
http://www.qodo.co.uk/blog/javascript-select-all-options-for-a-select-box here

Just have to change the buttons to checkboxes

Answer (score -1):

It's been done before although not via a checkbox but should be easily adaptable:

http://www.obout.com/mvc-listbox/apiclient/aspnet_apiclient_select_all.aspx

Comment: I know this link but this doesnt fit into my requirement. This code is for asp.net MVC 3rd party controls from Obout